# Issue with Payment while using Production Server- PayU

Tags: payment-gateway, payu

I have downloaded the asp.net MVC integration KIT from payumoney.com and tested it with test data on test server.It is working fine.

But when I am using the salt and key provided by the payU login and executing the code on the production server it gives me the following error which says Unable to process with the payment Merchant has to use his own email to make payment

[Issue With PayU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWbdI.png)

Comment: Are you using your own email to make the payment?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late answer to the question, but I thought it may be helpful to someone just like me who faced same issue.

**The reason behind this problem is that, your payU money merchant account is not activated properly to receive payments**. It takes nearly 7-10 days for activation. For activation details you can contact to payU Money support team.

Once your account is activated , you will not see this error anymore and can make payments with any valid email id.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

after purchased payumoney you can implement and make payment for testing by using your own registered email ... because your payumoney account is under activated process.... and it will take 4-7 days...

but if u implement payumoney code and testing your website, then u should have to used your email while payment testing process...  because payu is not approved your account .. it's under process